# With android Chrome, html option lists ignore my font size request

Tags: android, css, html, google-chrome, font-size

On an android tablet, using Chrome, I'm showing a custom web page.  In it I have some dropdown controls (HTML5 SELECT).  With these controls I'm trying to display more HTML OPTION elements by reducing their displayed size.  I'm not having success with my effort.  On my 7-inch tablet the options always show up with only about 12 elements filling the display (held in portrait mode).

For example, use this CSS:

```
#distDV {
    font-size: 8pt;
    border-color: #999999;
}

#distDV option {
    font-size: 8pt;
    border-color: #999999;
}
```

with this HTML:

```
<select id="distDV">
      <option value="30">+30</option>
      <option value="29">+29</option>
</select>
```

On a desktop computer (using Chrome v. 25 or later) the select drop-down displays in the smaller, requested font.  When I click on the control to show the values the options also are in a tiny font.

On my android tablet (using Chrome v. 25 or later) the select drop-down displays in the smaller, requested font.  When I click on the control to select a value the options are shown by the android device in a standard option select, full-screen, using about 12 lines top-to-bottom on my 7-inch display.  I'm trying to make this maybe 16 lines, doing this through CSS.

I'm looking for ideas.  Yes, I already tried using an optgroup, to no effect.

Thank in advance,
Jerome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out it's impossible to change the font size of the option select dialog. This is for very good usability reasons. Is there a reason why you need more options shown at once? Why is the dialog's scrolling not good enough for your needs? Also remember that if you make the options too small you may frustrate your users. You may be able to accurately select an option but other people may not.

All that said you could get round these limitations by coding your own dialog, perhaps by using radio buttons. For example:

```
<input type="radio" id="distDV30" name="distDV" value="30"><label for="distDV30">+30</label>
<input type="radio" id="distDV29" name="distDV" value="29"><label for="distDV29">+29</label>
```

You could then style that however you like. Another option would be to use an input box, which may be more appropriate if all your options are numbers. E,g.:

```
<input type="number" name="distDV" min="1" max="30">
```

Comment: *I* don't have a good reason for reducing font size, but another person on my project asked that more lines appear on the page.   As you say, I can use brand X drop-down or use a slider bar (which needs an extra control to display the current slider value).  'Nuff said, thanks for the answer.